# Distributed transaction between client -> server -> client

Tags: java, transactions, jms, jta, xa

For a new project i'm searching for technologies that will make my life a bit easier. My new project is basically 2 clients and a server:
client1 sends a message1 to server, server sends message1 to client2, client2 does something with message1.

This can be done with plain java sockets or rmi or similar technique. But here is the catch:
The entire process need to be a transaction. What i mean with this is that when client2 can't handle message1 client1 and server need to know this and rollback any actions that were done.

My first idea was to send a message from client2 to client1 and server with the result, but thinking more about it this would become error sensitive.

I already took a look at technologies like jms, jta, jca, but was a bit overwhelmed by everything. And i suspect there might be a easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that JTA or JMS alone would solve your problem, since even distributed transactions is still between transactional resources, such as a JMS broker and a database, not between applications.

I would still go for a transactional transport in your case, such as JMS. That would give you "guaranteed delivery", which perhaps would simplify the error handling.

```
1    c1 -> jms -> server -> jms -> c2   2

4    c1 <- jms <- server <- jms <- c2   3
```

If you do this right, you can be sure that c1 (and the server) eventually WILL receive a "result" from c2, good or bad.

If C2 crashes during processing and fails to send back a result jms message, the transaction will roll back, locally at c2, and c2 has to try again.

The down side of this solution is that messages might get "stuck", for instance if it cannot be processed at all by c2, however, it will never be lost. If you route a synchronous request (soap, RMI, simple tcp..), you can face a situation where the reply is lost and C1 will never know if C2 processed the message or not. This can to some point be avoided by making C2 idempotent and make C1 able to retry the transaction if there is no reply after some time.

As I see it, there is no "golden solution", but any option would do it pretty good. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply. I appreciate the thoughts on the subject. I've not yet made a desicion on how to "do" it, there is not much information easily available for such problems.

Comment: Addition: now looking into putting c2 behind a jca adapter that supports transaction. This might solve a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the server component, you can try using [Message Driven Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html) in a fully-fledged Java EE server like JBoss AS. In that case, you clients will use JMS to communicate with the server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But it doesn't solve my problem "the entire process need to be a transaction." With message driven beans i can only manage a transaction on for example the server and/or client. I cannot span the transaction at client1 and server and client2. Do you have an idea on how to solve that?